# Android Force using ARMv7 on io.realm library

Tags: java, android, arm, realm, abi

Hello

I have a big problem and I hope someone can help me.
I try to start my app on a galaxy S7 (Device on ARMv8)
My app have a library who don't support armv8 but this library work perfectly on the phone if no other library work in armv8.
And my problem is that I use Realm that is in ARMv8.
I can't delete the library, it will take too much time.

So my question is :
How can I force Realm start with ARMv7 ?

Best Regards,

Romain

Comment: what is your Realm version

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude any architecture (and thereby forcing Realm to use ARMv7) by adding a `packagingOption`. You can see how in the FAQ: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#couldnt-load-librealm-jniso